# How to print textual representation of single documents stored in a tm corpus in R?

Tags: tm

I was using {tm} package and then generated a corpus using

`corpus = Corpus(VectorSource(sample.words))`

then I want to check the content in corpus ,but it print this instead of its texts:

```
> corpus
<<VCorpus>>
Metadata:  corpus specific: 0, document level (indexed): 0
Content:  documents: 3933
```

Now I have found some methods to look into `corpus`,then I started wondering what exactly R print when an object was typed in ?

```
> class(corpus)
[1] "VCorpus" "Corpus" 
> typeof(corpus)
[1] "list"
```

Why it didn`t like other ordinary lists ,printing its columns and rows?Does this has something to do whit the *class* attribute?

I`m new in R and not familiar with some basic concepts, thanks for your patience!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The introduction document to the `tm` package says that you can use  , say, `writeLines(as.character(mycorpus[[4]]))` to get a textual representation of  document 4.

You can also use  `content(myCorpus[[23]])`.

To read the intro document, enter `browseVignettes()` on your R prompt and the search for it on the browser window that will have opened.