# How to correctly Load .txt files into Vcorpus in R?

Tags: r, text-mining, tm, corpus

All.
I want to analyze the content of several .txt files in R. I'm having trouble when importing them.
Here is my code (there are 238 .txt files in the data/txt/2012/ directory):

```
library(tm)   
cname <- file.path("../data", "txt", "2012")
docs <- Corpus(DirSource(cname), readerControl=list(reader=readPlain))
```

Now, if I take a look in docs its a Vcorpus with 238 documents as expected:

```
> docs
    <<VCorpus>>
    Metadata:  corpus specific: 0, document level (indexed): 0
    Content:  documents: 238
```

Here is where I get trouble understanding what is happening:

```
> docs[1]
    <<VCorpus>>
    Metadata:  corpus specific: 0, document level (indexed): 0
    Content:  documents: 1

> docs[[1]]
   <<PlainTextDocument>>
   Metadata:  7
   Content:  chars: 2156
```

The way I see it, there are two levels of Vcorpus, The first contains all 238 documents, the second has one document each. I want to have only one Vcorpus that has 238 documents and then the PlainTextDocument, expected output would be (notice I use only [1] and not [[1]] to get the PlainTextDocument):

```
> docs[1]
   <<PlainTextDocument>>
   Metadata:  7
   Content:  chars: 2156
```

Is there a way I can load the .txt files into a Vcorpus with the desired format?
Or I should work with the way that is being loaded now?

Thanks a lot.
Cheers.

Comment: Is there a problem with the current format? I don't understand what you want to change. And I think you just might not understand the difference between the `[ ]` and the `[[ ]]` operators. The former subsets a a list-type object and maintains the list-type structure while the latter extracts elements from a list. There are not two levels here. There is just a corpus that contains plaintextdocuments.

Comment: MrFlick, thanks for the comment. But what confuses me is that if there weren't two levels I would access the PlainTextDocuments just using one ´[ ]´ operator and not two ´[ [ ] ]´. But it seems I'm missing the point of the ´[  ]´ operator as you mention. I'll take a read on that. Thanks for pointing me out the direction.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print textual representation of single documents stored in a tm corpus in R?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34236346/how-to-print-textual-representation-of-single-documents-stored-in-a-tm-corpus-in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you have correctly loaded the corpus.

The introduction document to the tm package says that you can use,say, `writeLines(as.character(docs[[4]])`) to get a textual representation of document 4.

You can also use `content(docs[[4]])`.